# Type mismatch when setting startActivity() in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, type-mismatch

I'm new on Kotlin for programming Android mobile. I want to try to make my own movie list for my experiment from many tutorials and for Android mobile programming learning.

So, I want to try to make Explicit Intent that started from movie lists that one of them are clicked into an movie information that I clicked.

After I get movie datasets from JSON in MainActivity.kt, I use the code below in MainActivity.kt to MovieAdapter class (MovieAdapter.kt)

```
val customAdapter = MovieAdapter(moviePoster, movieTitle, movieYear, movieGenre, movieDirectors, movieRunTime, movieRating, movieActors, movieOverview, this@MainActivity)
recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter)
```

And this is the MovieAdapter class (MovieAdapter.kt)

```
class MovieAdapter(var moviePoster: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieTitle: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieYear: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieGenre: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieDirectors: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieRunTime: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieRating: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieActors: ArrayList<String>,
                   var movieOverview: ArrayList<String>, var ctx: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
```

Then in MovieAdapter.kt (MovieAdapter class) like in the code below

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int)
{
    holder.moviePoster.tag = moviePoster[position]
    holder.movieTitle.text = movieTitle[position]
    holder.movieYear.text = movieYear[position]
    holder.movieGenre.text = movieGenre[position]


    val moviePosterDetail = moviePoster[position]
    val movieTitleDetail = movieTitle[position]
    val movieYearDetail = movieYear[position]
    val movieGenreDetail = movieGenre[position]
    val movieDirectorDetail = movieDirectors[position]
    val movieTimeDetail = movieRunTime[position]
    val movieRatingDetail = movieRating[position]
    val movieActorsDetail = movieActors[position]
    val movieDescriptionDetail = movieOverview[position]


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{

        Intent(ctx, MovieDetail::class.java).also {

            it.putExtra("moviePoster", moviePosterDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieTitle", movieTitleDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieYear", movieYearDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieGenre", movieGenreDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieDirector", movieDirectorDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieTime", movieTimeDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieRating", movieRatingDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieActors", movieActorsDetail)
            it.putExtra("movieDescription", movieDescriptionDetail)

            startActivity(it)

        }

    }
}
```

In the startActivity(it) part, there is a error in below

> Type mismatch.
> Required: Context
> Found: Intent
> No value passed for parameter 'intent'
> No value passed for parameter 'options'

But in other files when do startActivity(it) part (in MainActivity.kt file), no error detected here.

So, why it is happened and how can I do this?
And if I must to use context and options parameters in startActivity(), what should I do to fill the parameters in startActivity() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to run an XML/View based project atm, but the `startActivity` you are calling might be the `ContextCompat` or something.

Since the name of your parameter is

```
var ctx: Context
```

where you passed the instance of your activity

```
this@MainActivity
```

Can you try using the `ctx` parameter calling the `startActivity` instead?

```
Intent(ctx, MovieDetail::class.java).also {

    ...
    ...

    ctx.startActivity(it)
}
```